# Liquibase doesn't fill contexts column in changelog table

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I'm using liquiBase 3.8.0 in springBoot. My tree of changelog files is like this:

```
changelog-master.xml
--changelog-test.xml
----changelog-1.0.0
----changelog-1.1.0
--changelog-prod.xml
----changelog-1.0.0
----changelog-1.1.0
```

I try to use contexts and I find strange behaviour -- if I use context in changelog-master.xml or changelog-test.xml like this (parents changelog files):

```
 <include file="test/changelog-test.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" context="!prod"/>
```

then liquibase doesn't fill contexts column in changelog table and contexts column is null.

But if I add attribute 'context' to 'changeSet'

```
<changeSet id="changelog_in_test_section" author="author@mail.ru" logicalFilePath="changelog-1.0.0" context="test">
```

After that the contexts column is filled with '!prod AND test'

**I want that the contexts column is alwayes filled (if I use context attribute in parent changelog).**

Answer (score 0):

I would add this to the github issues list.  Or better yet, if you have a code fix add it as a pull request.
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues

Comment: added https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1243